# Capybara: How to attach a file?

Tags: ruby, macos, google-chrome, cucumber, capybara

I have an element, clicking which I open the dialog window of adding a picture:

`<div layout="column" class="uploadPhotoActionBlock layout-align-center-center layout-column" layout-align="center center" ngf-select="vm.addPhotos($file)"
accept="image/*" ng-hide="vm.product.images.length == 3" aria-hidden="false"> <div flex="" class="plus flex"> + </div> <div flex="" class="text ng-binding flex"> add photo </div> </div>`

I need to do these steps in my test.

I tried:

1. attach_file
2. find.set
3. click button + click at (clicking inside the window)

Nothing works. 
Browser is Chrome.
[image]

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the actual `<input type="file">` element associated with the AddPhoto widget visible (you don't show the actual input in your html) and then call attach_file on that.  Usually that will mean using `execute_script` to adjust the CSS of the input element to make it visible.